# Function is not called on click event - Backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I am new to backbone and am trying a sample for click event. I have defined events in my view. Also, added function definition. But the click event is not calling my function. Please suggest changes in below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>


<div class="fileuploadView">

    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <button id="submitFile" type="button" class="btn" name="submitFile"> Submit </button>

</div>


<script>

    var File = Backbone.Model.extend ({

        defaults: {
            name : "",
            location:""
        }
    });

    var FileView = Backbone.Model.extend ({

        initialize : function () {
            alert('FileView initialized');
        },

        events : {

            "click .submitFile": "onSubmitFile"
        },

        onSubmitFile : function(event)
        {
            alert('backbone click event');
            console.log('backbone click event -on console');
        }
    });

    var fileView = new FileView ({el : $('#fileuploadView')});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably wanted to extend `Backbone.View` instead of `Backbone.Model` for `FileView`

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a problem with selector. Your event binding says

```
   events : {

        "click .submitFile": "onSubmitFile"
    },
```

But submitFile is actually id. So change it to

```
   events : {
        "click #submitFile": "onSubmitFile"
    },
```

Also FileView should extend Backbone.View not Backbone.Model

Answer (score 0):

You're using backbone model instead of view, use '.' for classes or '#' for id's.

Try to do this.

```
                   //View instead of model
var FileView = Backbone.View.extend ({

    initialize : function () {
        alert('FileView initialized');
    },

    events : {

        "click .submitFile": "onSubmitFile"
    },

    onSubmitFile : function(event)
    {
        alert('backbone click event');
        console.log('backbone click event -on console');
    }
});

var fileView = new FileView ({el : $('#fileuploadView')});
```